# What is a good opening time for an IDE (Pycharm)?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

i am using Pycharm for Python and when i start the program, it takes around 10 or even more minutes till the program starts to run. I wonder if that is a normal case?

Comment: This is a really hard question to answer properly. Whilst the answer is probably 'No, that's not normal'. it depends entirely on your OS, RAM available, CPU usage, processor etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invalidating your caches by going to File > Invalidate caches / Restart and then wait for your code to be re-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1, standard Asus laptop, SSD. I takes me about 8 seconds to start PyCharm.
Definitely not normal in your case.